# Changing routes if laravel app exists inside a directory

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel app that is inside a directory called app. Inside my apache host, i have pointed the app to the public directory and everything works. However, if i have two applications one called `app` and another called `app2`

and they both have the routes

```
Route::get('/copyright_policy', [AdsController::class, 'copyright_policy'])->name('copyright_policy');
Route::get('/faqs', [AdsController::class, 'faqs'])->name('faqs');
```

Is there a way i can ensure the routes have a prefix from the folder the app resides in like `app/faqs` and `app2/faqs` for instance?

Comment: Can you add the line that contains the configuration in your Apache host?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that in RouteServiceProvider. Here is how I implemented in my project,

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    Route::prefix('exotel/')
        ->middleware('web')
        ->group(base_path('routes/exotel/exotel.php'));
}
```

Comment: he has 2 apps. not 2 route files